# Assign heading color to indicate content

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm using a jQuery Accordion and would like to dynamically alter the colour of one of the section headers to identify if that one section has any content entered.

The section relates to file notes, and if notes have been added, I would like to highlight the title header red as a warning and to draw attention so the notes are not missed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tb9j98zp/1/)

Change background color for `h3` with id: "`ui-accordion-accordion-header-0`", "`ui-accordion-accordion-header-1`"... et cetera

e.g.:

1. accordion header:

   ```
   $('#ui-accordion-accordion-header-0').css('background','red');
   ```
2. accordion header:

   ```
   $('#ui-accordion-accordion-header-1').css('background','red');
   ```

Comment: Being a little green, I assume I use an if/then function to choose between the two accordion styles?

Comment: I'm still a little confused by the answer. I understand setting up two different target states for the style, but cant see how to implement the activation dependent upon content. For example.   "default empty state = 0. If text box contains text, display state= 1".

Comment: that's great, not quite what I was after, but its pointing me in the right direction! really appreciate your help :)